# Is It Possible to Get the Privacy of Users' Posts Sent from My Application?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm new in Facebook Graph API.
I design a website and let users can share a story on their FB wall.

After user share it successfully, I get the response of `post_id`.
Like `1096684890353086_1096740930347482`

I think the first part of `post_id` (`1096684890353086`) is the **special new user id** which consists of `user_id` or the `app_id` since it is neither my personal `user_id` nor my application's `app_id`.

Assume my personal `user_id` is `{user_id}`, the post can also be found if I use `post_id` as `{user_id}_1096740930347482`. It means I can get the post's information through 
https://graph.facebook.com/v2.6/{user_id}_1096737970347778?access_token={my_personal_access_token}

But I can neither get the information through 
 https://graph.facebook.com/v2.6/1096684890353086_1096737970347778?access_token={my_personal_access_token}


nor through 
https://graph.facebook.com/v2.6/1096684890353086_1096737970347778?access_token={my_application_access_token}

These ways will get

```
{

    error: {
        message: "Unsupported get request. Object with ID '1096684890353086_1096737970347778' does not exist, cannot be loaded due to missing permissions, or does not support this operation. Please read the Graph API documentation at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api",
        type: "GraphMethodException",
        code: 100,
        fbtrace_id: "BE+XF/DCc7z"
    }

}
```

Since I want to check whether user set the sharing post PUBLIC, I would like to use my application's access token and the responsed `post_id` to get info through Facebook Graph API.

Is it possible to get other user's post from my application by using my application's access token?

Comment: _Why_ do you want to check if they shared publicly? You are aware that you are not allowed to reward users for sharing in any way, right?